# How do I rename a collection?

Tags: collections

I read that in 2.80, double-left clicking a collection enables you to rename it, but I'm not finding this to be the case. How do you rename a collection?

Answer (score 3):

Yash's solution works, but you can also Right click, click ID Data and then rename.

Comment: for some reason I can't double-click on stuff to rename - objects, collections, etc so this is the solution for me as well. My theory is that my computer is too slow.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it just by double clicking <kbd>LMB(Left Mouse Button)</kbd> on the Name.
[image]